# Add zip files from one archive to another using command line

Tags: macos, bash, zip

I have two zip archives. Say, `set1` has 10 csv files created using Mac OS X 10.5.8 `compress` option, and `set2` has 4 csv files similarly created. I want to take the 4 files from zipped archive `set2` and add them to list of files in archive `set1`. Is there a way I can do that?

I tried the following in Terminal:

```
zip set1.zip set2.zip
```

This adds the whole archive `set2.zip` to `set1.zip`, i.e., in `set1.zip` now I have:

```
file1.csv, file2.csv,..., file10.csv, set2.zip
```

What I instead want is:

```
file1.csv, file2.csv,..., file10.csv, file11.csv, ..., file14.csv
```

where, `set2.zip` is the archive containing `file11.csv, ..., file14.csv`.

Thanks.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/92963/how-to-combine-merge-zip-files

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a built-in OS X tool, but there's a [zipmerge](http://nih.at/libzip/zipmerge.html) utility as part of the [libzip package](http://nih.at/libzip/index.html) ([hg repository](http://hg.nih.at/libzip/) available).

Answer (score 1):

```
unzip set2.zip -d .tmpdir; cd .tmpdir; zip ../set1.zip *; cd ..; rm -r .tmpdir;
```

Answer (score 0):

This script here should do it.

zipjoin.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#Example: ./zipjoin.sh merge_into.zip merge_from.zip
mkdir .tmp
unzip $2 -d .tmp
zip $1 .tmp/*
rm -r .tmp
```

Hope that helps!